# Is there a BNF grammar of the TeX language?

Tags: tex-core, parsing, grammar

I'm looking for a BNF grammar of the TeX language, does it exist?

## EDIT

For those of us who are not computer scientists, a BNF grammar is one kind of formal description of a CFG: [Backus Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

For those who don't know their Chomsky, a CFG is a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), which means (very roughly) that substitutions can be made independently of their use context.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

### Parsing TeX is Turing complete

TeX can only be parsed by a complete Turing machine (modulo the finite space available), which precludes it from having a BNF.  This comes from a combination of two features: first, TeX is Turing complete (if you need proof, [this Turing machine simulator](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908020612/http://en.literateprograms.org:80/Turing_machine_simulator_%28LaTeX%29) should suffice); and second, TeX can redefine macros (and their parsing rules) at runtime.  Since TeX can require that macros be followed by specific characters, redefining a macro can mean redefining the syntax of TeX.  Combining these facts means that we can write TeX code like the following, where `\f` is defined to be the algorithmic representation in TeX of some arbitrary (computable) function *f* : ℤ → ℤ:

```
\def\TuringCompleteness#1#2{%
  \edef\Output{#1{#2}}%
  \ifnum\Output=0
    \def\Required!{Bang!}%
  \else
    \def\Required?{Huh?}%
  \fi}
\TuringCompleteness{\f}{0}
\Required!
```

Will this TeX parse?  That depends on the value of *f*(0) / `\f{0}`!  And since TeX is Turing-complete, computing this value may require a full Turing machine, and therefore so will determining whether or not `\Required!` is valid TeX syntax.

### It gets worse: category codes

Perhaps, though, you think that you can still perform a rough check for code that looks like a backslash, followed by letters, followed by braced stuff.  This will already get inadequate quickly, but that's not all.  If delimited macros weren't bad enough, things get even worse when you realize that the reason that the characters `\`, `{`, `}`, `$`, and so on have the behavior they do is simply because TeX specifies that they have particular "category codes".  The ability to redefine these means that writing TeX like

```
\catcode`\~=0
\catcode`\]=1
\catcode`\[=2
\catcode`\}=12
\catcode`\{=12
\catcode`\\=12
```

means that all *subsequent* (La)TeX code must be written like so:

```
~textbf]This is bold-faced text.[  This text contains a literal backslash
(~texttt]\[) and literal curly braces (~texttt]{}[).
```

to get output like so:

> **This is bold-faced text.**  This text contains a literal backslash (`\`) and literal curly braces (`{}`).

### Constructive Proof that TeX is (at least) Context-Sensitive

Additionally, inspired by [TH.'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/is-there-a-bnf-grammar-of-tex-language/4203#4203), here's a specific constructive proof that TeX is not context-free.  And note that it doesn't have to rely on catcode trickery—just TeX's ability to define arbitrarily-delimited macros.  (Yes, this is implied by the first section, but it's still nice to see a specific case in action.)

```
\newcount\nesting

\def\RecognizeABC#1{\begingroup
  \nesting=0
  \OneStep#1\relax
  \ifnum\nesting=1
    There was \the\nesting\ copy of each control sequence.\par
  \else
    There were \the\nesting\ copies of each control sequence.\par
  \fi
\endgroup}

\def\CheckFinished#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \def\OneStep#1{\relax}%
  \fi
  \OneStep#1}

\def\OneStep\a#1\b#2\c#3\relax{%
  \advance\nesting by 1
  \CheckFinished#1#2#3\relax}
```

This code is set up to recognize what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Examples) calls "the canonical non-context free language" of *n* copies of `\a` followed by *n* copies of `\b` followed by *n* copies of `\c`, where *n* is at least one.  The first line just allocates a counter; we'll use this to keep track of how many copies of the control sequences we see, but it's just so we can display some text at the end, not for parsing.  To attempt recognition of some text, call `\RecognizeABC{...}`.  This simply sets `\nesting` to zero (for, again, output purposes), and calls `\OneStep`.  `\OneStep` is set up to take three arguments *delimited by `\a`, `\b`, and `\c`*.  The first argument must come between `\a` and `\b`, the second between `\b` and `\c`, and the third between `\c` and `\relax`.  If there are the same number of each of `\a`, `\b`, and `\c`, then this will eventually be `\OneStep\a\b\c\relax` and all the arguments will be empty.  With `\OneStep`, we just record the fact that there's one more of each `\a`, `\b`, and `\c` (which is, again, just for output), and then we see if we're done.  `\CheckFinished` looks to see what the next token in the input stream is.  If it's `\relax`, then the arguments were empty, and we're done; redefine `\OneStep` not to do anything.  Now, call `\OneStep`—whether it's the parsing macro or nothing at all—on the remaining input stream, recursing.  Once we're done, we finally finish `\RecognizeABC`, where we typeset how many copies of each control sequence we saw.

Phew!  If you didn't follow all that, here's what a trace looks like, if we only look at the important macros:

```
[START] \RecognizeABC{\a\a\a\b\b\b\c\c\c}
    --> \OneStep\a\a\a\b\b\b\c\c\c\relax
                  -#1-  -#2-  -#3-
    --> \CheckFinished\a\a\b\b\c\c\relax
    --> \OneStep\a\a\b\b\c\c\relax
                  #1  #2  #3
    --> \CheckFinished\a\b\c\relax
    --> \OneStep\a\b\c\relax
          (All the arguments are empty.)
    --> \CheckFinished\relax
    --> ``There were 3 copies of each control sequence.''
```

Thus, the following TeX

```
\RecognizeABC{\a\b\c}
\RecognizeABC{\a\a\b\b\c\c}
\RecognizeABC{\a\a\a\b\b\b\c\c\c}
```

Yields the following output:

> There was 1 copy of each control sequence.
>   There were 2 copies of each control sequence.
>   There were 3 copies of each control sequence.

But TeX such as

```
\RecognizeABC{}
\RecognizeABC{\a}
\RecognizeABC{\a\a\b\b\c\c\c}
\RecognizeABC{\a\b\c\garbage}
```

fails.

---

**Edit 1:** In addition to minor bugfixes/cleanup and breaking the answer into sections with headings, I expanded the rationale for TeX being unparsable by anything short of a Turing machine to hopefully make it slightly more clear.  This involved removing the previous `\weird` example, replacing it with something that's more of a proof.  If you'd rather have a concrete *example* (but non-proof) with a command which redefines *itself*, consider the following TeX, which was there before:

```
\def\weird[#1][#2]{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \def\weird!{I was previously called with a relaxing first argument.}%
  \else\ifx#2\relax
    \def\weird(##1){I can only be called with one argument; I was given (##1).}%
  \fi\fi
  I was called with [#1] and [#2].}
```

To start, `\weird` must be called as `\weird[stuff][other stuff]`.  But if its first argument is `\relax`, then it redefines itself to require being called as `\weird!`; if its second argument is nothing, it redefines itself to require being called as `\weird(stuff)`; and it always typesets text.  This can't be captured by a BNF grammar (I don't think).  And of course, in the general case, we need a Turing machine.

Comment: Very nice answer! It might be easier to read if you removed the unnecessary comments at the ends of most of the lines. (Only six lines in your lists need comments, one of which is missing one. The others are unnecessary.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I always obsessively comment out my line endings (I'm annoyed I missed one :-/), even though I could remove the comments; I'll do that now.

Comment: Gotta be careful with numbers. Something like `\def\foo{2x} \ifnum1=1%[newline here]\foo\fi` has potentially surprising behavior.

Comment: That did not occur to me.  Programming in TeX: there's never a dull moment!  (I didn't miss any this time, did I?  :-) )

Comment: It's what makes TeX so much fun to program in. It's always a puzzle!

Comment: Fantastic answer. This question comes up periodically, and I've never seen such a useful reply.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer, I knew nothing about catcode. It seems that parsing tex is not a simple task as I thought before. My final task is to extract all math formulas from a set of articles (in tex), I thought I could parse them to do it, but now I'm not sure about it. What approach could you recommend? I think casual articles do not use catcode, so to extract correct math formulas I may parse tex and process newcommand. The alternative is to try use existing engine to parse and extract the needed information from its internals.

Comment: @rystsov: I think the best approach is to make assumptions. Assume that your TeX files use only a certain set of standard packages and certain user-defined macros. Write your parser so that it only tries to understand this particular tiny subset of TeX. Be conservative: whenever your parser sees something that it does not understand, throw an error. The end result is likely something very specific to *your* own style of using TeX in your articles, but it might be enough for your needs. Most importantly, this allows you to extract "semantic" things (e.g., the parameters of your own macros).

Comment: @rystsov: I'm glad my answer helped.  As for your specific question, what Jukka said makes sense; I'd also suggest taking your comment there and making it a new question of its own.  You never know what someone will come up with.

Comment: Great answer.  It will be mandatory reading for my Computer Science Students during the discussion of BNF.

Comment: Hi, I can't prove that there is no BNF grammar for tex but I would like to argue against coupl eof points made in the answer:

Answer (score 28):

Just to add another angle to the excellent posts by TH. and Antal, is that besides TeX being a Turing complete machine, it can also be coerced to do lambda calculus, the
basis of all functional languages. On CTAN there is a package called [lambda-lists](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lambda-lists) developed by Alan Jeffrey that implements, among other lambda concepts,
unbounded lists. Not only does TeX do  all these, but impressively, the routines were implemented in TeX's mouth, proving that **TeX's mouth** is as powerful as any computer anywhere.

To understand the relationship between the lambda calculus and Turing machines one needs to refer to the [Entscheidungsproblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem) which is  one of the famous 23 problems proposed by  David Hilbert.

In 1936 and 1937 Alonzo Church and Alan Turing respectively, published independent papers showing that it is impossible to decide algorithmically whether statements in arithmetic are true or false, and thus a general solution to the Entscheidungsproblem is impossible.

This was done by Alonzo Church in 1936 with the concept of "effective calculability" based on his λ calculus and by Alan Turing in the same year with his concept of Turing machines. It was later recognized that these are equivalent models of computation. The work of both authors was heavily influenced by Kurt Gödel's earlier work on his incompleteness theorem - Wikipedia

So the lambda calculus, Turing machines and TeX are not just closely related but they are equivalent models of computation and this is one of many aspects that makes TeX and friends interesting!

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the terminology, ‘TeX's mouth’ refers to the scanning stage before macros and registers can be set (although their contents can be retrieved); i.e, code involving only `\ifx`, `\expandafter`, `\csname`, `\the`, etc. etc., but not `\def`, `\let`, and others. When a macro is said to be ‘expandable’, this means it executes in TeX's mouth.

Comment: TeX's eyes look at lines of .tex-input-files and cause TeX to put characters in TeX's mouth.TeX's mouth creates tokens. **Expansion of expandable tokens takes place in the gullet** (and in the TeXbook is called a regurgitation-process). Assignments are done in the stomach. (See the begin of TeXbook Chapter 24: Summary of Vertical Mode: ...

Comment: ...  TeXbook Chapter 24: Summary of Vertical Mode: *We shall study TeX's digestive processes, i.e., what TeX does with the lists of tokens that arrive in its “stomach.” Chapter 7 has described the process by which input files are converted to lists of tokens in TeX’s “mouth,” **and Chapter 20 explained how expandable tokens are converted to unexpandable ones in TeX’s “gullet”** by a process similar to regurgitation. When unexpandable tokens finally reach TeX’s gastro-intestinal tract, the real activity of typesetting begins, and that is what we are going to survey in these summary chapters.*)

Comment: Both the TUGboat-article "[Lists in TeX's mouth](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-2/tb28jeffrey.pdf)" TUGboat, vol.11, no.2, pp.237-245 and the entry for the package [lambda-lists](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lambda-lists) at CTAN are inaccurate as there it is stated that expansion takes place in TeX's mouth although the TeXbook itself clearly says that expansion takes place in the gullet(, which is supposed to be the thing between mouth and stomach).

Comment: @UlrichDiez To be honest, I never understood why Knuth used the body parts analogies to explain TeX; a more familiar from a CS point of view terminology would have been better.  There is a mention of TeX in the Red Dragon book for compilers, which says .( from memory) ...  that the tokens swim in a sea of letters! I will have another look at your observations.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I can't speak for Knuth, but I guess he meant to create an analogy for people who aren't as computer-savvy that involves something they're familiar with. In "TeX: The program" Knuth uses different terminology. As for observations: I have made the observation that the TeXbook is a book where one must also pay attention to what is **not** said: In TeXbook, 24, where the analogy to the living organism is referred to, chapters 7 and 20 are mentioned: In chapter 7 it is said that only eyes and mouth see the lines of TeX input and that tokens are sent from mouth to stomach. How...

Comment: @YiannisLazarides ... How the sending process is done and what happens in the sending-process is omitted at this point. In chapter 20 the generation of tokens is called a mastication-process (mastication=chewing?) and it is distinguished from digestive-processes and it is explained that all digestive processes are applied to tokens and that expansion belongs to the digestion processes. But nothing is said at this point about which "body parts" carry out macro-expansion.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Tokens swimming in a sea of letters is also a nice analogy. But I see the analogy a little differently: TeX's mastication and digesting processes are not applied directly to .tex input files. The .tex input file is viewed line by line by TeX's eyes, and each line is treated as a series of instructions to put characters/letters into TeX's mouth, which in turn are tokenized in the mouth. These characters/letters must come from somewhere. They cannot be the characters/letters of the .tex input file, because the .tex input file is not disassembled/destroyed, but remains...

Comment: @YiannisLazarides ... but remains unchanged and can be compiled again and again. *(Exception: Cases where input files contain instructions to overwrite input files.)* Perhaps these characters/letters come from the sea in which the TeX organism swims around. In this analogy, the tokens would not be swimming in a sea of letters, but the TeX organism itself would be swimming in a sea that also contains letters. The TeX organism would represent a container that keeps the things that exist inside it (which include the tokens) separate from the sea outside.

Answer (score 14):

It's extremely unlikely. TeX can change how it parses input while it's in the middle of reading the input. I'd have to think a bit longer, but I think that precludes TeX from having a context-free grammar and thus it could have no BNF.

Answer (score 5):

I can't prove that there is a BNF grammar for Tex but I would like to argue against couple of points made in Antal's answer:

1. There are examples of Turing machine simulators in C/C++/Java on the same website mentioned above. That does not mean you can't write a BNF grammar for C/C++/Java.
2. The fact that Tex lets you change the category code or meaning of command codes does not mean Tex is context sensitive from a parser's point of view. This is related to the semantics of Tex. I think this is analogous lexical scope in languages like Java. You can have two different variables with same name in the same java class where one is a class field and the other one is a local variable. And the type of these two variables can even be different. That does not mean Java parser is context sensitive.

Sorry that I have posted this as a separate answer but the site won't let me make this long comment.

Comment: The difference between TeX and most languages (one might say "sensible languages") is that these sorts of changes can affect the *parsing* of TeX.  (I imagine Perl might have similar problems thanks to source filters and `BEGIN` blocks?)  For instance, `\ifx\f\g\catcode\`\\{=12\fi{}` is a parse error if and only if `\f` and `\g` are equal; and as discussed above, the Turing-completeness of TeX (and [of TeX's mouth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4224/1425)!) means that the equality of `\f` and `\g` is undecidable.  Does that help clear things up?

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky: This answer makes two very valid points. In C it is also possible to write a program that recognizes a^nb^nc^n. Also in C, you cannot decide whether two functions f and g are equal. What exactly do you mean by Turing-completeness of TeX? C ist also Turing-complete in the sense that what can be computed by a TM can also be computed by a C program. I fail to see the proof in your answer above.

Comment: @alexraasch: The difference – and this is subtle! – is that in TeX, *parsing* is Turing-complete, not simply evaluation.  In C, we know that `a + b * c` is syntactically valid as long as `a`, `b`, and `c` are arbitrary syntactically valid expressions.  In TeX, the expression `\a + \b * \c` may trigger a parse error depending on the definitions of `\a`, `\b`, and `\c`.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky: OK, thanks for the clarification. Does your "Constructive Proof" above show the Turing-completeness of parsing TeX? It seems to me you're talking about the evalutation of the program not the parsing process itself.

Comment: @alexraasch: It does show Turing-completeness, b/c it talks about *both* – parsing can do evaluation! My use of a `\RecognizeABC{…}` macro obscures that slightly, I know, b/c we're used to that being a guaranteed-to-parse form that just evaluates; however, that's *not* what's going on. Rather, it expands to include the string `\OneStep…\relax`, where `\OneStep` only parses when followed by an `\a`, a `\b`, & a `\c` (with some intervening junk, and followed by `\relax`). `\OneStep` keeps expanding recursively, and eventually either *fails to parse* or terminates when reaching the empty string.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky: I have one more question, if I may. Does "Turing-complete" in this case mean recursively enumerable or decidable? Thanks.

Comment: @alexraasch: The language consisting of all valid TeX programs should, if I am thinking about this right, be recursively enumerable.  That's because the following semidecision procedure works: run `tex` on the file.  If it halts without a parse error, accept.  If it halts with a parse error, reject.  If it doesn't terminate, well, you should've rejected but you can't.  (Although: with TeX's oddly intermixed nature of parsing and execution, it's not 100% clear to me that "nontermination" means "syntactically invalid".  But I can't figure out any other way for it to go!)

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky: Well, you can write a TeX program that contains an infinite loop but it may still be syntactically valid. So I think we need another proof. It will probably be rather complicated because of the parse-eval intermixing, as you said.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky: Maybe, we better continue on the CS sub-forum, if you're interested. :-)

Comment: @alexraasch: But it's not obvious that such a program "may still be syntactically valid".  Is the program `\def\loop{\loop}\loop}\bye` invalid?  How about ``\def\loop{\loop}\loop\catcode`}=12 }\bye``?  Or how about ``\def\x{…}\def\loop{\loop}\loop\ifnum\x=0\catcode`}=12\fi}\bye``?  It's not clear what it means to say that a TeX program after an infinite loop even has a well-defined syntactic validity; you can't check such validity without running the program!  So I'm leaning towards the conclusion that a TeX program can only be syntactically well-formed if parsing and evaluation terminates.

Answer (score 1):

You can always examine the original [source code](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web) for `TeX` (`LaTeX` is built on an extension of `TeX`). It is highly readable (thanks to his proprietary WEB language) and, in fact, compiles to a readable `TeX` document using `weave` (built in to most `TeX` distributions).

With regards to parsing, here's a summary of the important bits (from the most disgusting facts to the least disgusting):

- While defining a command, *anything* can be put as parameter delimiters (comments work as is, but the spacing will be messed up). For example,

  ```tex
  \def\test |\a#1@$^&^TRDFS(#2


  |{5#1#25}

  \test|\a {f}@$^&^TRDFS(f


  | % This prints 5ff5
  ```

  `TeX` matches parameters based only on code points and categories (macro definitions are completely ignored). This is the reason why the top answer's "constructive proof" works out.
- `^^@` is synonymous to an ASCII `<null>`...in fact, suppose we have `^^n` where `n` is an ASCII character. If the code point of `n` is less than 64, then add 64 and return. Else, subtract 64 and return. Moreover, `^^XX` is synonymous to a character with code point `0xXX` (in HEX).

  - It gets worse... `\t^^65ste` is equal to `\tAste`. You can even define `\tAste` using `\def\t^^65ste`.
  - Fortunately, this is ignored in parameter delimiters (no comment).
- `TeX` has some context-free components with respect to a different alphabet. If we consider `TeX`'s alphabet as pairs `a:c` where `a` is an ASCII character, and `c` is its (symbolic) category code, then, e.g., `TeX` numbers (see the `scan_int` procedure) can be written in EBNF as follows

  ```
  decimal_number = ("+:other_char" | "-:other_char")* digit+
  digit          = "0:other_char" | ... | "9:other_char"
  ```
- Erasing semantics, `TeX` has (E)BNF using only category codes. For example,

  ```tex
  control_sequence = escape (letter)*
  ```

  This is precisely how a `lexer` would tokenize `TeX`. The context sensitivity comes from dynamically taking action after consuming each token.

Comment: Well, ^^A is ASCII code point 1, not null, null would be ^^@