# Standalone LaTeX editor/renderer for Windows?

Tags: editors, windows

Is there any **small** and **simple** program (or even library) that can render LaTeX locally as you type?

I'm looking for something pretty much like [this page](http://vps.arachnoid.com/latex/), which auto-renders immediately as you type, except that it:

- Must not need any internet connection
- Should be as "lightweight" as possible (it shouldn't even depend on a browser, if that can be avoided... a standalone executable would be ideal)

(The goal is to avoid going having to go through the pain of creating LaTeX documents every time you want to write a little expression to paste somewhere else, but *without* needing an internet connection or another program to run it.)

If there is even a C/C++-compatible *library* that could convert a basic LaTeX equation to a PNG file (or SVG or whatever), that would be fine too; I could write a front-end for it pretty easily.

Comment: Try [gummi](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/). I use it on Linux but they say there is a Windows .exe as well.

Comment: By 'LaTeX' here do you mean TeX-like math input? The linked web page certainly does not recognise for example `\begin{document}`!

Comment: @vaettchen: The server seems down right now. xD I'll check it later, thanks.

Comment: @JosephWright: Oh yes, right... should've said TeX I guess. :)

Comment: You could also take a look at http://www.texify.com/ but is online-only, AFAIK.

Comment: If you were using Mac OS, then you could use [LaTeXiT](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/). It sounds exactly like what you are looking for.

Comment: @matth: It... does. o.o wow, it looks nice!

Comment: @matth: Ohey I just searched for `LaTeXiT windows` and found [these](http://alternativeto.net/software/latexit/?platform=windows)... specifically, [KLatexFormula](http://alternativeto.net/software/klatexformula/). The font is ugly/too soft for my eyes but otherwise it seems to be what I want...

Comment: @matth: LaTeXIT requires an installation of TeX.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Ah yeah, that's a bummer...

Comment: If you have `TeX` installed you could simply use [tex to image over command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line). It doesn't render as you type, but is the equivalent to a standalone executable and does not require you to create a complete document just to get an image of a formula.  It will also allow you to use the full power of `TeX` in terms of any packages that you may desire.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The website you point to is using MathJax to render the LaTeX. If you don't mind using a browser, then you can simply [download MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/zipball/v1.1a), unpack the zip file, go into the test subfolder and open `sample-dynamic.html` in your browser. This is effectively an equation editor. You can make a custom web page to cater to your needs.

[image]

Note: As it is this requires you to hit the return key to render. That should be simple enough to alter. Grabbing the equation as a PNG could be a little more complex to achieve.

Comment: In terms of "lightweightedness", what is the size of the download? Also, would it be possible to modify the code to typeset the equation on-the-fly rather than pressing RETURN? These are just inquisitive questions...

Comment: Since the site that the question points to is using MathJax and updates on the fly, yes to the second question. The download is ~15MB, so it depends on your definition of light. Lighter than a full install of TeX Live anyway. ;)

Comment: I kinda already knew about MathJax but was hoping for something more lightweight (15 MB is kinda huge for this, especially when combined with a > 20 MB browser)... +1 thanks anyway.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The problem you're going to have is that TeX is simply big. If you want even a fraction of the functionality then I'm afraid you're stuck. Perhaps you can strip out some of the unnecessary fonts that come with MathJax. A modern system should include the necessary fonts without having to use them. You can also strip out `docs` and perhaps more stuff taking you down to 5MB.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: Hmm... I might actually give that a try, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any small and simple program (or even library) that can render LaTeX locally as you type?

The only freely available program that I know of which can handle on-the-fly rendering of TeX and friends is [LyX](http://www.lyx.org).

---

> (The goal is to avoid going having to go through the pain of creating LaTeX documents every time you want to write a little expression to paste somewhere else, but without needing an internet connection or another program to run it.)
>
> If there is even a C/C++-compatible library that could convert a basic LaTeX equation to a PNG file (or SVG or whatever), that would be fine too; I could write a front-end for it pretty easily.

As far as libraries go, you could look into running [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org). This could be embedded into a C++ program using the WebKit browser or even into a command-line tool using a "headless" browser like [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org). Some more options are listed in:

[What parsers for (La)TeX mathematics exist outside of the TeX engines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4223/what-parsers-for-latex-mathematics-exist-outside-of-the-tex-engines)

The issue that prevents a proliferation of good parsing libraries for TeX math is that TeX has a context-sensitive grammer that can be altered on the fly. Because of this, it is easy to come up with pathological examples that will confound any parser that is not TeX:

```
\catcode`/=13
\let/\over

$y = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}} / {2a}$

\end
```

Add users eventually wanting to use "a specialized macro from LaTeX package X" and the most robust contenter left is an actual TeX engine.

Comment: +1 for PhantomJS, it would be useful for other things as well; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to your needs probably is [latexmk](http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/support/latexmk/). *Every time you save your #.tex-file,* `latexmk` runs LaTeX, pdfLaTeX and probably even LuaLaTeX, plus BibTeX, if you need that also. I propose to use Sumatra-PDF to view the PDF. This great piece of software does not lock the PDF, when opened, so `latexmk` can change the PDF and Sumatra-PDF will render it more or less immediately.

Maybe you can connect a second screen to your computer and have on one screen your *.tex-file and on the other the PDF.

Besides that: Compiling your document every second probably won't work, while you type. Any open bracket will cause an error.

Comment: What you describe, does only work with the `-pvc` option, or has the default behaviour been changed?

Comment: @Speravir Yes, -pvc is needed, or more generally: you have to set up latexmk properly to use it the way I described.