# Automatic Way of Searching for Syntax Inconsistencies

Tags: syntax, syntax-checker

I have a large .tex file, and when ran am receiving error messages about missing `$` or extra delimiter/missing `{`. It tells me in the log file where the error is "supposed" to be located, but it is not there. I believe it is somewhere else in the file though. My question, is there an automatic way of FINDING exactly where the syntax inconsistencies in your file are when the log file just provide a line number and even then sometimes it gives incorrect line number locations such as: having one brace `{...` with no closing brace, or having one math delimiter `$...` or `\(...`, and missing the other. A small 
snapshot is below of what was reported back after compilation.

[image: log output]

And this is what my `line 16` looks like below:   [Line 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC9ib.png)

[image: Line 16]

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but I would guess you have `\(` in a caption. Delete the `.lof` file and add `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` and `\(` will become robust.

Comment: If you run `pdflatex` with the command line option `-file-line-error`, you'll discover that the error is *not* at line 16 of the main file, but in the `.lof` file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: +1.. This work flawlessly. Thanks to being first on the scene. `:p`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. This is useful. I'm sure running this `-file-<...>-<...>` has other useful applications to it as well. I will look into this further.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer in full generality is no. There is not. This is due to issues outline in [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4205/215). In short, LaTeX can change what the symbols mean in ways that it is tricky for a "syntax checker" to follow.

I'm sure some editors do a better job than others at doing this, and so I fully expect a better answer to this question to appear.