# Using newcommand with math environment

Tags: texstudio

I defined a new command as:

```
\newcommand{\eq}[2]{\begin{equation}\begin{split}#1\end{split}\label{#2}\end{equation}}
```

so to make a new equation I do:

```
 \eq{equation stuff here}{label here}
```

But since I've not used the equation environment explicitly, texstudio highlights every math symbol in the equation. It is really annoying. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  (I moved my first comment to an answer, since I'm very confident that there *is* no answer.  If someone proves me wrong, I'll be impressed :-). )

Comment: I advise you not doing that, because you lose information. For instance, you can't look for all the labels with a simple find function for `\label`. Maintenance of compact code is harder.

Comment: I suggest you to use the capability of TeXstudio to autocomplete the commands instead of defining new ones.

Comment: egreg, I do prefixes to my labels, e.g. fig: or eq:, so finding them wont be a problem. Vedran, That seems like a reasonable compromise, thanks a lot. P.S. Being a new user, I cannot add comments, so I must post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're content with replacing the command `\eq` with the environment `eq`, this should be doable. Just define your own CWL file with the line

```
\begin{eq}#\math
\end{eq}#S
```

Then include this file in options, under *Completition*.

More on the CWL format can be found [here](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) and the basic info on the file itself is [here](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040).

Comment: Since I don't use TeXStudio anymore, I didn't know about this functionality.  Neat!  I would note to @Harsh though that environments can also take arguments.  So, whether or not it's A Good Idea, you could incorporate the automatic label as an argument in much the same way as you would do in `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 2):

Given the nature of TeX's language, I don't think there is a good, reusable solution to this one. Syntax highlighting is something done usually using regular expressions, but TeX is (literally) a class of languages higher than regular expressions can cover. Getting the syntax highlighting right would require some serious umph behind TeXStudio's parser - paramount to including a TeX distribution in-house.

See also [Is there a BNF grammar of the TeX language?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201).

Comment: I was a bit pessimistic about the problem. I guess I can just turn off the highlighting in texstudio. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can define something like that:

```
\def\eq$#1${\begin{equation}#1\end{equation}}


\eq$
a(b+c)=ab+ac,
\label{distriblaw}
$
```

and you have both shorthand and highlighting!

(Read Knuth's TeXbook rather than LaTeX tutorials to know how to define commands properly. ;-) )

Here are some more of my own definitions:

```
\def\eq#1$$#2$${\begin{equation#1}#2\end{equation#1}}
\long\def\subeq#1{\begin{subequations}#1\end{subequations}}
\def\Split$$#1$${\begin{split}#1\end{split}}
\def\Align#1$$#2$${\begin{align#1}#2\end{align#1}}
\def\Aligned#1{\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}}
\def\Gather#1$$#2$${\begin{gather#1}#2\end{gather#1}}
\def\Gathered#1{\begin{gathered}#1\end{gathered}}
\def\Multline#1$$#2$${\begin{multline#1}#2\end{multline#1}}
```

Examples:

```
\Align*$$
a&=b+c,
\\
e&=fg.
$$

\Align at$${2}
a&=b,&c&=d,
\label{eq1}
\\
e&=f,&g&=h.
\label{eq2}
$$
```

Comment: using `$$` in latex removes the ability to use some useful features that have been provided by the named latex environments, such as `\qedhere` with `amsthm`.  although ingenious, this is not a practical solution.

Comment: These are the best set of macros I have found so far. You get the highlighting and also the nice detail that TeXStudio can give you a formula preview when you hover over them with the mouse, which doesn't happen in ``\begin{equation}``. Really cool!