# Where is the MiKTeX list of keywords?

Tags: miktex, keywords

I recently downloaded Basic MiKTeX 2.9.4813..

I'm trying to find on the MiKTeX dir a file containing a list of all general keywords for LaTeX languages but can't find any...

Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
What do you mean by 'keyword'? Do you want a list of programs included in MikTeX or a list of commands (like `\title{...}`) available?  (Try putting `texdoc latexcheat` into the command line.)

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a project to develop a LaTeX compiler and want to identify if the user wrote a keyword so I can mark it in a specific color. For that I'm searching for a file containing all keywords..

Comment: You're not going to find one—use regular expressions: `\\[@A-z]*\*?`

Comment: Can you please provide me more details about your answer?

Comment: Yet another compiler? Which features should this compiler offer that we do not already have?

Comment: @daleif [raises a good point…](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

Comment: Here we go again: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/is-there-a-bnf-grammar-of-the-tex-language/4205#4205 `:)`

Comment: It's a study project...
Is there a simple way to track common commands like 
Begin, End, etc'?

Comment: @NirB no there is no way, the tokenization and keywords (as you call them) may be changed arbitrarily within the document: thereis no fixed grammar.

Comment: @NirB: I go for Sean Allred's answer. Follow his hints and you will highlight all commands (that's the easiest way). For details about stackexchange go to the [Help Center](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within TeX systems, it is always possible to define new commands:

```
\def\somemacro\with#1\weird#2,#3\delimiters{#1, #2, #3}
\newcommand \somenewcommand[1] {some expansion using #1}
% ... the following with `xparse` and `expl3` as appropriate
\NewDocumentCommand \SomeCrazyCommand {m m o O{default} u{(} t! r][}{...}
% ... used as \SomeCrazyCommand{...}{...}[what?] this is arg 5(!]and 6[%end
\cs_new:Nn \you_can't_even_rely_on_the_hash:NnN {something~ with~ #1,~ #2~, and~ #3}
```

The only mostly constant thing is what counts as a command: it consists of a backslash (`\`) introducing either one symbol or a string of letters, thus the regular expression `\\(.|[A-z@]*\*?])`.  (`@` is often used as a letter in LaTeX internal macros.  Also, many LaTeX commands have starred variants.)

Trying to compile such a list would be difficult, but you can take a look at the AUCTeX project for Emacs—within the style files exist convenient lists of commands for particular packages.

Comment: In pure TeX you can only define a new command with `\def`. `\newcommand` is a LaTeX command. ;)

Comment: @someonr Or `\ExplSyntaxOn \use:c { some_weird_arg_based_command_#1 }`,`\cs_new:Nn \@@_internal_package_macro:Nnx \ExplSyntaxOff`… the list goes on.  TeX's Turing completeness throws a wrench in just about every hopeful parser.

Comment: For a stress test look up `xii.tex` on CTAN, http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/xii

Comment: @daleif Didn't David Carlisle write this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104248

Comment: @SeanAllred I think so yes, just to show that making a parser is not a trivial matter. Though the example is TeX and the OP refers to LaTeX.

Comment: who, me :-) ???