# Is LaTeX a context-free grammar?

Tags: parsing

How can you tell if something is a CFG or not? I am wondering if you could create a math/LaTeX parser using a parsing expression grammar (PEG), or not. Is this possible, and how can you tell?

Comment: No, TeX is at least context sensitive. *Edit:* this answer might enlight things: [Parsing TeX is Turing complete.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4205/3094)

Comment: @PauloCereda Which makes this question a duplicate since BNF and context-free grammars are equivalent. Edit: Malipivo was a bit quicker :)