# Is there a BNF-grammar for simple constructs of the TeX language?

Tags: languages, parsing, grammar

[(Previously)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/is-there-a-bnf-grammar-of-the-tex-language)

Is there a TeX grammar that parses simple constructs like document, enumerate, section, subsection, etc.?  I'm not interested in parsing complicated constructs requiring a more complex computational model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no.

longer answer there are of course grammars for various subsets. One possible starting point would be the flex source of the tex grammar used by the tth system. It's not that accurate for modern real world latex files, but it will parse a core subset well enough (or at least it used to, I haven't tried it for a *long* time)/

http://hutchinson.belmont.ma.us/tth/

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on it now and I'll post it as an answer when I'm done.

Comment: Where is the flex file?  I looked in the source for tth and ttm but only found the flex output as a C file.  Thanks!

Comment: @cxw I haven't looked for 10 years or so, I thought that I remembered it used to be public perhaps it's been withdrawn, you'd need to ask the author.