# Tab based syntax wrapper around LaTeX?

Tags: syntax

In text file formats, if one allows for tab based formatting one can simplify things considerably.  Are there any simple syntax wrappers that compile directly to LaTeX?  I'm thinking of something that is to LaTeX as Markdown is to HTML and basic Less is to CSS.

Given a BNF of LaTeX syntax, it shouldn't be more than a clever 100 lines of a ruby/python script.  I'm not looking to change the inner guts of say the math environment, just looking for an equivalent of 'outer' syntax without so many "\"'s and "{}"'s.

**Edit:**  Since the langauge of valid LaTeX doesn't have a BNF, I'll have to settle for a syntax wrapper of **a large subset of LaTeX**.  I think the syntax of most working, practical LaTeX could be described as a context free grammar.

Comment: [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) provides this functionality, I think.

Comment: Regarding BNF: [Is there a BNF grammar of the TeX language?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4201)

Comment: Are you looking for an indentation-based syntax where indentation denotes block structure (like in Python or Haskell)?

Comment: Christian Lindig, yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for.