# Is there a BNF Grammar for tex math expression

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, languages

Like this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/is-there-a-bnf-grammar-of-the-tex-language).

I have a similar question about that. Is there a BNF grammar for tex math expressions?

Comment: There is a grammar for the tex primitives in the texbook but not for the syntax that is allowed in tex documents including macro expansion as that can not be expressed in bnf

Comment: all the discussion in the linked question to show there is no bnf for tex apply equally to math expressions, so I think that this is a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm sorry about not explaining it clearly. What about if we do not consider macro expansion in the tex math expressions. It's a subset in a total tex document.

Comment: You would have to be a lot more specific as there are almost no math commands defined by default, for example `\sqrt` is a macro, `\alpha` isn't a primitive but is defined via a `\mathchardef`  something like amsmath `align` is hundreds of macros implementing a custom syntax. there is _nothing_ math-specific about tex parsing. So any answer here would apply equally to the linked question.