# Remove a specific latex command from the text AND closing bracket behind it

Tags: text-manipulation

How to remove a specific latex command from the text AND closing bracket behind it, but to keep the text inside the brackets/

senseless example:

```
We \edit{Introduce a} model for analyzing \emph{data} from various
experimental designs, \edit{such as paired or \url{http://www/}
longitudinal; as was done 1984 by NN \cite{mycitation} and by NNN
\cite{mycitation2}}.
```

Output:

```
We Introduce a model for analyzing \emph{data} from various
experimental designs, such as paired or \url{http://www/}
longitudinal; as was done 1984 by NN \cite{mycitation} and by NNN
\cite{mycitation2}.
```

PS. I am introducing a lot of small edits into my tex file. I want those edits to be highlighted, so my collaborator can see them. But afterwards I would like to remove all highlights and to send the text to a reviewer.

The question was originally asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373662/awk-sed-remove-a-specific-latex-command-from-the-text-and-closing-bracket-behind. But example there was too soft

Comment: @den2042: do you want to disable the highlighting (see TH's answer) or do you want to change the source, i.e. remove `\edit{` and the closing`}` from it?

Comment: @Teepeemm, there's a second `\edit{such as ... \cite{mycitation2}}`.

Comment: @Mike I would like to change the source, i.e. remove \edit{ and the closing} from it. The reason for that is there maybe many more consecutive overlapping edits. I would like to send the clean text to each collaborator

Comment: @den2042: that's a job for regular expressions, which I don't know well enough for this, sorry.

Comment: If you would have similar question, please check ilkkachu answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373772/remove-a-specific-latex-command-from-the-text-and-closing-bracket-behind-it/

Comment: Okay, if you want to remove it from the source, then TeX SX is likely not the correct place to ask. @Mike said this is a job for regular expressions, but that's wrong. The set of valid LaTeX source files is not a regular language. Indeed it is not even [context-free](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4205/647).

Answer (score 2):

## New answer

Since it sounds like you want to modify your source code, I've written a new nonanswer.

This is not something that you want to be doing from within TeX. You might be tempted to try to write a regular expression for it, but you're not going to succeed using real regular expressions.

A better solution might be to instruct your editor to do what you want. For example, in Vim, with the cursor over the `\` in `\edit{...}`, entering `` 5xma%x`ax `` deletes the first 5 characters (the `\edit`), marks the current location (the `{`), moves to the matching `}`, deletes it, moves back to the marked location and deletes it. Combined with `/\\edit{` as part of a VIM macro makes deleting them pretty easy.

Credit to [Justin Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084210/remove-a-pair-of-parentheses-brackets-or-braces-in-vim) for the `` ma%x`ax ``. (Or as the edit notes, ``` %x``x ``` has the same effect as `` ma%x`ax ``.)

## Old answer

This answer assumed you wanted to simply make `\edit` not do anything which it's now clear is not what you want.

You want to (re)define `\edit` to just output its argument without change.

```
\renewcommand\edit[1]{#1}
```

Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand\edit[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

%\renewcommand\edit[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
We \edit{Introduce a} model for analyzing \emph{data} from various
experimental designs, \edit{such as paired or \url{http://www/}
longitudinal; as was done 1984 by NN \cite{mycitation} and by NNN
\cite{mycitation2}}.

We Introduce a model for analyzing \emph{data} from various
experimental designs, such as paired or \url{http://www/}
longitudinal; as was done 1984 by NN \cite{mycitation} and by NNN
\cite{mycitation2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I uncomment the `\renewcommand` line, I get the following.

[image]

In this case, the two paragraphs are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on Python, not concise enough but performs well with nested commands.

```python
def command_remove(tex_in, keywords):
    # Romove command with curly bracket
    # keywords: "hl textbf" mean removing \hl{} and \textbf{}
    pattern = '\\\\(' + keywords.replace(' ', '|') + '){'
    commands = re.finditer(pattern, tex_in)
    idxs_to_del = [] # The index of }
    for command in commands:
        stack = 0
        current_loc = command.span()[1]
        while not (tex_in[current_loc] == '}' and stack == 0):
            if tex_in[current_loc] == '}':
                stack = stack - 1
            if tex_in[current_loc] == '{':
                stack = stack + 1
            current_loc = current_loc + 1
        idxs_to_del.append(current_loc)

    idxs_to_del = sorted(idxs_to_del, reverse=True) # sort
    tex_list = list(tex_in)
    for idx in idxs_to_del:
        tex_list.pop(idx) # remove }

    tex_out = ''.join(tex_list)
    tex_out = re.sub(pattern, '', tex_out) # remove \xxx{
    return tex_out
```

It locates the target command by regular expression and then locates the position of the closing bracket with a stack. For `tex_out = command_remove(tex_in, "revise textbf")` with `tex_in`:

```latex
\hl{Can you} \revise{can a \textbf{can} as a \emph{canner} can} can a can?
```

[image: tex_in]

we would get `tex_out`:

```latex
\hl{Can you} can a can as a \emph{canner} can can a can?
```

[image: tex_out]

More details, i.e., command line running, are in [Latex_command_remove](https://github.com/mzh045/Latex_command_remove).

Answer (score 0):

Though an old post, it might still be relevant and interesting.

Here's an approach using package `changes` from [ctan](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changes).

First, let's have a look at the original snippet, replacing the `\edit{}` statements with code from `changes`, using the `[draft]` option. I included a `\listofchanges` at the end, which can be further adjusted via options.

[image: code with changes]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% ~~~ this one is newly introduced here ~~~~~
\usepackage[draft]{changes}% <<< draft

% ~~~ to define ID's and assign colors ~~~~
\definechangesauthor[color=orange]{DEN}\definechangesauthor[color=red]{ME}

\begin{document}
% ~~~ replacing \edit{ } from original ~~~~
We 
\added[id=DEN]{Introduce a} 
model for analyzing \emph{data} from various experimental designs, such as paired or \url{http://www/} longitudinal; as was done 1984 by NN \cite{mycitation} 
\deleted[id=ME,comment={just to show this feature}]{and by NNN\cite{mycitation2}}
.

\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\listofchanges

\end{document}
```

~~

Finally let's have a look at what happens to the same code, when switching to the `[final]` option for the package: It keeps all changes-code, but reworks the output pdf as needed.

[image: final-option]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% ~~~ this one is newly introduced here ~~~~~
\usepackage[final]{changes}% <<< switching to final

% ~~~ to define ID's and assign colors ~~~~
\definechangesauthor[color=orange]{DEN}\definechangesauthor[color=red]{ME}

\begin{document}
% ~~~ replacing \edit{ } from original ~~~~
We 
\added[id=DEN]{Introduce a} 
model for analyzing \emph{data} from various experimental designs, such as paired or \url{http://www/} longitudinal; as was done 1984 by NN \cite{mycitation} 
\deleted[id=ME,comment={just to show this feature}]{and by NNN\cite{mycitation2}}
.

\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\listofchanges

\end{document}
```

~~

To remove all changes-markups, apply `script pyMergeChanges.py`, as described in the manual.