# Turn question and choices of exam class to csv (with a python? Perl? script)?

Tags: python

**Question**

How do I handle the extraction of the `.tex` file (as described below) to a flat csv (with format below) ?

**Context**

I created all my MCQ with `exam`. However, exams are now 100% online... (sigh)

My LaTeX file has the basic following format

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
​
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
 \question What is the answer ? 
 \begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice 70
 \choice 75
 \choice $80 \times \Delta$
 \CorrectChoice 85
 \choice None of the above
 \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I need now to provide a csv where the questions of the MCQ above would be displayed like (**Inc**orrect,**Cor**rect, just to be clear

`question,answer1,Cor/Inc,answer2,Cor/Inc,answer3,Cor/Inc ,answer4,Cor/Inc,answer5,Cor/Inc`

And it would render like

`What is the answer ?,70,Inc,75,Inc,"$80 \times \Delta$",Inc,85,Cor,None of the above,Inc`

Each line would obviously be a new question.

**What could correspond so far**

I found something interesting in python, but I am more open to a solution than a type of programming.

I see the principle for environment between `\begin` and `\end` thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054008/extract-figures-from-latex-file

```
infile = open('MCQ.tex', 'r')
outfile = open('FlattenMCQ.csv', 'w')
extract_block = False
for line in infile:
    if 'begin{questions}' in line:
        extract_block = True
    if extract_block:
        outfile.write(line)
    if 'end{questions}' in line:
        extract_block = False
        outfile.write("------------------------------------------\n\n")

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

**Where I am stuck**
The recurisivity to test first `\begin{questions}` then `\question` then  `\begin{oneparchoices}` then `\choice` or  `\CorrectChoice`

NB : I posted initially this question there  [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65008969/edit) but probably makes more sense here.

Comment: It is usually considered impolite to crosspost (better link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65008969/2336725).  This is more of a SO question than a TeX question.

Comment: @Teepeemm Oh is it  (impolite) ? I did not have much luck on SO, I thought i'd probably be more lucky to have an aswer here. What do you recommend ? I close my question here ?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564420/is-there-a-python-module-for-parsing-latex

Comment: @Marijn :) I'll look merci !

Comment: @Marijin You've just given me the distance (very very long) between me and what I need to do :)