# Redefining questions environment in exam to use longtable

Tags: longtable, exam, automation

I am trying to redefine the `questions` environment and take each `question` and put it inside a `longtable` environment so that the first column will have the question number, and the middle will have the question content and the last column will have the points for the question.

Our faculties may type the questions using exam class only. And I strongly believe there should be a way to redefine the way the questions are printed. I have looked into the `exam.cls` but does not able to figure out where is the exact command which puts them in the list and how it adds the points in the margin or wherever required.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question First question,
\begin{parts}
    \part[5] First part
    \part[5] Second Part
\end{parts}
\question Second question,
\begin{parts}
    \part[5] First part
    \part[5] Second Part
\end{parts}
\question[10] Third question with no parts...
 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

### The expected output:

[image]

Comment: The `exam`  package seems to be built upon lists, which is essentially incompatible with tables. It might be easier to write a new package with similar API.

Comment: Your problem is somewhat similar to [mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572445/turn-question-and-choices-of-exam-class-to-csv-with-a-python-perl-script). I needed to extract the content of the lists in `exam`. Python or perl scripts were the options.