# How is TeX/LaTeX parsed?

Tags: tex-core, syntax, grammar, definition

I have some  questions about TeX/LaTeX parser and parsing TeX/LaTeX after reading the following:

> ## Limitations when parsing TeX as a context-free grammar
>
> This is a PEG parser, which means it interprets LaTeX as a context-free language. However, TeX (and therefore LaTeX) is Turing complete, so TeX can only really be parsed by a complete Turing machine. It is not possible to parse the full TeX language with a static parser. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/is-there-a-bnf-grammar-of-the-tex-language) for some interesting examples.
>
> It is even undecidable whether a TeX program has a parse tree. There has been done some research on the problem of parsing TeX, see [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/%7Eseba/publications/sle10.pdf).

Source: https://github.com/michael-brade/LaTeX.js/blob/master/README.md

- What are the parsing rules used in TeX/LaTeX?
- If this is not a context-free grammar what is the type of grammar used?
- What is the parser used in TeX/LaTeX and how does it prase a TeX/LaTeX document?
- How is the parser written/generated?

Comment: I take it you've seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/is-there-a-bnf-grammar-of-the-tex-language?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: there is no grammar it is a custom parser written in pascal, look at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/plain/contrib/xii/xii.tex this is plain tex but not amenable to any parser generated by standard parser generators from a grammar

Comment: @JosephWright Yes

Comment: Check the Blog entires by Graham Douglas, here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/A_six-part_series:_How_do_TeX_macros_actually_work%3F